# Is there a way to replace some quotation marks with preg_split and to leave some out?

Tags: php, preg-split

I'm trying to use `preg_split()` but the results aren't what I expect to get from the function.

I'm new to php and the whole `preg_split()` scene and it seems to complicated for me to understand, at least for the moment.

```
$row = "EL10,40,2019-02-06,55555,2019-01-06,ar@email.com,"Text , random text , 52555885/ 48484848484",Yes,One Two,Broke,2019-01-01,000.00,0.00,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.00,0.00,0.0,VRA "Morning";

$row_expl = preg_split('/(?:[^"]*"|)\K\s*(,\s*|$)/',$row);
```

I expect to remove comma delimiters while leaving commas in quotation marks.

Everything almost seems to work, the only problem occurs at the very end.
It adds extra quotation marks to: `VRA "Morning"`.
The result seems like this: `"VRA ""Morning"""`

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: I expect it to remove delimiters but keep  ' VRA "Morning" ' unchanged. I found the preg_split somewhere, but I don't quate know what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex actually is the wrong tool for your problem. A CSV parser that defines the delimiter and enclosure character is the tool you need.

```
str_getcsv('EL10,40,2019-02-06,55555,2019-01-06,ar@email.com,"Text , random text , 52555885/ 48484848484",Yes,One Two,Broke,2019-01-01,000.00,0.00,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.00,0.00,0.0,VRA "Morning')
```

The default delimiter for the `str_getcsv` is `,` and the enclosure character is `"` so should be all set with the default options. You can see more about the function here http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php.

https://3v4l.org/GFWkr